# MDX equivalent to SQL subqueries with aggregation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm new to MDX and trying to solve the following problem.  Investigated calculated members, subselects, scope statements, etc but can't quite get it to do what I want.

Let's say I'm trying to come up with the MDX equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(netMarketValue) net, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN netMarketValue > 0 THEN netMarketValue ELSE 0 END) assets,
  SUM(CASE WHEN netMarketValue < 0 THEN netMarketValue ELSE 0 END) liabilities,
  SUM(ABS(netMarketValue)) gross
  someEntity1
FROM (
SELECT SUM(marketValue) netMarketValue, someEntity1, someEntity2
FROM <some set of tables>
GROUP BY someEntity1, someEntity2) t
GROUP BY someEntity1
```

In other words, I have an account ledger where I hide internal offsetting transactions (within someEntity2), then calculate assets & liabilities after aggregating them by someEntity2.  Then I want to see the grand total of those assets & liabilities aggregated by the bigger entity, someEntity1.

In my MDX schema I'd presumably have a cube with dimensions for someEntity1 & someEntity2, and marketValue would be my fact table/measure.  I suppose i could create another DSV that did what my subquery does (calculating net), and simply create a cube with that as my measure dimension, but I wonder if there is a better way.  I'd rather not have 2 cubes (one for these net calculations and another to go to a lower level of granularity for other use cases), since it will be a lot of duplicate info in my database.  These will be very large cubes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave the aggregation logic to the cube--that's what it does best.

In your case, I would create an account dimension, and then I would [add Account Intelligence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174759.aspx). However, this only works for the Enterprise edition of SQL Server (2005 and above).

If you happen to have the standard edition, the canonical way to do this is [to use unary operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175417.aspx).

That's the way we used to do it with Sql Server 2000, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902636(SQL.80).aspx) you have a great example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not two cubes, but one cube with two fact tables (sometimes called a constellation schema). The question was written months ago so I won't elaborate more here unless someone asks for more info.